# Mongo db connection timing out in AWS Lambda serverless

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, mongoose, aws-lambda, serverless

I have a nodejs AWS Lambda function set up on serverless.
This connects to MongoDB using mongoose.
Below is how I've set up the connection.

```
database.js

const mongoose = require('mongoose');

if(mongoose.connection.readyState != 1) {
    mongoose.connect(mongo_uri, {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true
    });
}

const db = mongoose.connection;

db.once("open", function(callback) {
    console.info(`Connected with status: `+db.readyState);
});
db.on('error', function(error) {
    console.error(`Connection error with status: `+db.readyState, error);
});
```

```
awsFunction.js

import("./database.js");

// ignore the following syntax. Just a basic example.
// Essentially the db is connected when the findById query is hit
 
const lambdaFunc = async () => {
const result = await mongoModel.findById({ _id: someId });
}
```

Now at certain points when my Lambda function is called, the db gets connected, it works fine for some time & then it times out after 6.01s. The 6s is AWS' default. But it looks like my mongoDB connection is what is causing the timeout. I'm not getting a response even though the "maxTimeMS" is 50. Because of this all subsequent calls to the function are timing out. I'm not entirely sure what is happening here. I'm not closing the connection at any point. Since it is serverless the mongoose connection is set up on every cold start. Which happens quite frequently.

1. Is the mongodb timeout happening because I'm not closing any of the connections? If so how do I close the connections & when do I do it?
2. Is there a way to elegantly handle the mongodb timeout (50ms) so that it does not end up timing out the AWS function (6s)?
3. Even if the mongodb times out for a particular AWS function call, can I ensure that the next call is not affected?
4. Is there a way to persist the mongoDB connection across multiple AWS cold starts?

Answer (score 0):

Technically, 6s is not AWS lambda default timeout, it's 3s.  So you must have made it 6s.

1. Very likely.  First off, you need to set keepAlive on mongo config, otherwise, while the lambda is warm, and no traffic is being sent over to mongo, mongo will kill the connection.  You should additionally have logic in here to handle the disconnect and retry mechanism.  Being in lambda is irrelevant in this case.
2. keepAlive needs to be set. You may also want to read up on poolSize, connectTimeoutMS, and socketTimeoutMS.  Without retry logic, your lambda will never be able to communicate with mongo again, so any future function call to the warm function will timeout due to node not being able to send any data.
3. See point #2 and #1 above.
4. No.  The definition of a cold start is that a brand new container is spun up, and has no ability to reference handlers in other instances.  Warm functions have the privilege of re-using whatever was in the primary scope of the function (outside the handler).

Comment: As part of point 1 how do I handle the disconnect & retry mechanism? Based on the code I've set up in database.js is there an event I should be listening to?

Comment: Actually - looking at point #1 around the retry, you do seem to have it correct.  I just don't use callbacks anymore, I use async/await.  Eg:

`try {
  let mdb = await mongoose.connect(dbConnection, options);
  // connection is good
} catch (e) {
  console.log("error:", e);
}`